# How to use JavaScript file without putting script tag in index.html?

Tags: typescript, angular, webpack

In production mode I have to serve my files from `dist` folder. My `node_module` folder is located outside the `dist` folder.

When I put `<script src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js" />` in `index.html` it won't find the file as I am serving my files from `dist` folder. When I import jQuery in `vendor.ts`, it does not work.

*How to make it work **without** using script tag in `index.html?`*

Comment: `When I import jquery in vendor.ts` is not enough for us to figure out what you have.

Comment: We need more information to be able to help. From the sound of it you are using a module bundler like webpack - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using webpack

Answer (score 0):

If you import the jquery file:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
// use $
```

then webpack will just bundle it for you don't need to put in a script tag.

Comment: I want to import bootstrap-datepicker. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Every JavaScript requires script tag

Assuming you have following directory structure is

node_modules/

dist/

....index.html

And you want to load jquery from node_modules/ in your index.html. Then your script tag should be

```
 <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: It was script tag, so it was not posting as plain text :)

Comment: All the src path in script tag must be in relative to you html file.